# Suppose a sequence has a bounded subsequence. Show that the sequence is monotone and bounded.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm not really sure how to go about showing this.

Answer (score 4):

It will be very difficult, as it is false.  For example $(0,1,0,2,0,4,0,8,\dots)$ has a subsequence that is all zeros.

Comment: I must have read the problem incorrectly. I think we can assume the sequence is monotone, and we only have to show that it is bounded which seems easier to do. Since the sequence is monotone and the subsequence is bounded, then the sequence will be bounded.

Comment: Yes, you can do that.  You are depending on the fact that after any element of the sequence there is an element of the subsequence.  Without the monotone it fails, because then the subsequence doesn't tell us anything about the omitted terms.